# How to properly replicate StepObject from Cept to Cest

Tags: php, codeception

Consider the following StepObject:

```
namespace Step\Acceptance;

class UserStep extends \AcceptanceTester
{
    public function login()
    {
        $I = $this;
        $I->amOnPage('/user/login');
        $I->fillField('username', 'user');
        $I->fillField('password', '123456');
        $I->click('Login');
    }
}
```

And now I'm going to use it in a Cept:

```
use Step\Acceptance\UserStep;

$I = new UserStep($scenario);
$I->login();
// change e-mail
// change password
// change profile
// etc
// log out
```

In the above scenario, the user will login **once** and attempt to accomplish all listed tasks.

Now, I'll use the same principle in a Cest:

```
class UserCest 
{    
    function changeEmail(\Step\Acceptance\UserStep $I)
    {
        $I->login();
        // task        
    }

    function changePassword(\Step\Acceptance\UserStep $I)
    {
        $I->login();
        // task        
    }

    function changeProfile(\Step\Acceptance\UserStep $I)
    {
        $I->login();
        // task        
    }

    function logout(\Step\Acceptance\UserStep $I)
    {
        $I->login();
        // task        
    }
}
```

Now using Cest when I run the tests the user will actually login **4 times** over. This will also happen if I use `@before` or `@depends` annotations and also when using `_before()`.

**Is there a way to persist and run the `login()` step object *once* when using Cest?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **StepObject** should be changed to the following:

```
public function login()
{
    $I = $this;

    if ($I->loadSessionSnapshot('login')) return;

    $I->amOnPage('/user/login');
    $I->fillField('username', 'user');
    $I->fillField('password', '123456');
    $I->click('Login');

    $I->saveSessionSnapshot('login');
}
```

This will not only persist and run the step object only once, but also brings the convenience of showing only one time the login steps in the console output.

Another great convenience is being able to properly leverage the `@before` annotation.

You could for example call the login step from a **BaseCest**, so login is now available in all your Cests and you can use `@before login` conveniently everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think writing first test

```
function login(\Step\Acceptance\UserStep $I) {
    $I->login();
}
```

and make the others depend on it

```
/**
 * @depends login
 */
function changeEmail(\Step\Acceptance\UserStep $I)
{
    $I->login();
    // task        
}
```

Should do it.

Comment: The question mentions `This will also happen if I use @before or @depends annotations and also when using _before().`